# Duplicates of .desktop files in Linux

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, .desktop

I have a duplication of NetBeans for .desktop . I cannot find where these .desktop files are, I have searched for them using the GUI file explorer and cannot find them. And yes, I have looked in `/usr/share/applications` and i still cannot find them there. I have uninstalled NetBeans and reinstalled it, however the .desktop entry is still there? Is there anyway to remove 2 and keep the proper one?[image: 3 NetBean .desktop entries]

Answer (score 0):

### Check within `${XDG_DATA_HOME}`, `${XDG_DATA_DIRS}`

Per the [XDG Spec § *Environment Variables*](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables) these will be set to `~/.local/share`, `/usr/local/share`, and `/usr/share` if not specified. Within each those directories, you should see an **`applications`** folder.

---

### tl;dr

Checking within

- `~/.local/share/applications`
- `/usr/local/share/applications`

would likely show these up, I'd guess.

Answer (score 0):

Or else

```
sudo find / -name *.desktop | grep -i netbeans
```

If they are anywhere else.

Comment: or `sudo find / -name '*.desktop' -iname '*netbeans*'` if you have GNU find and would like to do it all in one command